# SQLight dialect in Dropwizard for Hibernate

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, dropwizard, dialect

I'm Creating a project for tailor system as a RESTful web service using dropwizard and SQLight as database with hibernate.The problem is that hibernate have no dialect for SQLight so by searching got a class code for SQLightDialect.

now I have to add SQLightDialect class for hibernate to use and don't know how to do it in dropwizard.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding

```
Map<String,String> s=new HashMap<String, String>();
    s.put("hibernate.dialect","Hibernate.SQLightDialect.SQLiteDialect");
    dbconfigurations.setProperties(s);
```

in

```
public class databaseConfiguration extends Configuration {

@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty
DatabaseConfiguration dbconfigurations = new DatabaseConfiguration();

public DatabaseConfiguration getDatabaseConfiguration() {
    //return dbconfigurations;
    Map<String,String> s=new HashMap<String,String>();
    s.put("hibernate.dialect","Hibernate.SQLightDialect.SQLiteDialect");
    dbconfigurations.setProperties(s);
    return dbconfigurations;
}
}
```

Another Solution read on the [Web](http://johnewart.net/posts/2012/11/dropwizard_postgis/) is adding it in yml file like:

```
database:
# the name of your JDBC driver
driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
# the username
user: username
# the password
password: password
# the JDBC URL
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gis_database
properties:
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```